# How to redirect to the route in Angular if URL corresponds to the special pattern?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards, angular-guards

I have the URLs:

- /example.com/**client**/page-1?param=data
- /example.com/**client**/page-2
- /example.com/**client**/page-3?newparam=data

I want to redirect user to the following pages while they open the app:

- /example.com/page-1?param=data
- /example.com/page-2
- /example.com/page-3?newparam=data

How can I implement this in Angular? (e.g routes, guards, canActivate method or smth else)

Answer (score -1):

Normally, if you have pagination, the api takes care of that and when switching to another page index, you just need to pass the value to a parameter like this.

```
/example.com?pageIndex=1
```

And when navigating with a query parameter, you can achieve it by doing this.

```
this.router.navigate(
['/example.com'],
{ queryParams: { order: 'popular' } }
);
```